# Using part of a user defined function

Tags: function-construction

I've defined a simple function $f:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^2$. Is it possible to use only part of it?

```
X = {{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {4, 4}};
qVec = Array[q, 3];
a = 1/2;
n[qVec_List] := Transpose[X].qVec^(1/a)
```

If I define

```
needs = Transpose[X].qVec^(1/a)
```

I can use, e.g., `needs[[1]]` to obtain  `q[1]^2 + 2 q[2]^2 + 4 q[3]^2` and find its minimum. I'd be interested in being able to do the same thing with `n[qVec_List]`.

Comment: I might not fully understand your question, could you not use: 
n[qVec][[1]]?